# Assigning two column association to third column

Tags: excel

I have following structure in Excel 2010

```
Col1  Col2   Col3
12    C.E    C.E
13    D.C.E  C.E
14    P.E    P.E
100   A.O.H  A.O.H 
             C.E
             P.E
             ...
             ...

Output:   Col3
          12
          12
          14
          100
          12
          14
          ...
          ...
```

That is Col1 and Col2 are logically linked that means C.E has value 12 and D.C.E has value 13.What I want is that assign those association to Col3 that is where ever there is C.E no matter how many times it will be replaced by 12 and where ever there is P.E it will be replaced by 14.
I am having hard times doing it please guide me how to do it?

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking.  Can you specify desired input and output clearly?

Comment: It isn't clear from the program logic why `Col3` doesn't equal `13` in row 2. Do you always take the lowest possible substring match from `Col1`?

Comment: @JustinJDavies I think it's clear that he's using the first two columns as a kind of dictionary. No need for substrings IMO.

Comment: Possibly. I now see what you mean; it still isn't clear to me why row 2 of `Col3` would match `C.E (12)` rather than `D.C.E (13)` Could you edit the question to clarify the logic?

Comment: C.E=Chief Engineer    D.C.E=Deputy Chief Engineer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you swap the first two columns, you can use the `VLOOKUP` function to get the value associated with particular text, like so:

```
Col1   Col2   Col3   Col4   
C.E.   12     C.E
D.C.E  13     C.E
P.E    14     P.E
A.O.H  100    A.O.H 

Col4 Cell Value = VLOOKUP(Col4Cell, $Col1$FirstRow : $Col2$LastRowWithData, 2, 0)
```

Note that you cannot directly replace the values in `Col3` because that would lead to circular references - check for value in cell and replace in same cell!

Answer (score 0):

I think the following formula works:

```
=IF(LEN(B2)<>LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B2,"C.E",""))
,12
,IF(LEN(B2)<>LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B2,"P.E",""))
  ,13
  ,B2))
```

However this doesn't use the columns as the data source, it is purely hard-coded. You wopuld need to clarify your question if you want a generic answer.

Comment: User question unclear at time of posting, I don't believe this answer will cover the general case as it stands.